# EC DiffieHellman Private Key from windows store

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0

In application using .Net Standard 2.0 I want to load ECDiffieHellman private key for further computation using Bouncy Castle. I've checked certificate with posted code. For keys(1-3) I'm getting null value. I can obtain private key only using the last method 'GetECDiffieHellmanPrivateKey' but that is available since .Net 6.

```
X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(...);
X509Certificate2 cert = certs[0];

var key1 = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
var key2 = cert.GetDSAPrivateKey();
var key3 = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

var key4 = cert.GetECDiffieHellmanPrivateKey();
```

Looking for a way to load that key from store. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _.NET Standard 2.0_ is not an Application target - it's only for use by libraries. If you're targeting only the Windows Store then you should use the current .NET version: .NET 7.

Comment: I know it is not Application target. It is a standard what can be done either by .Net Framework since 4.6 or new .Net. The library that I'm creating is meant to be portable between .Net Framework and .Net >6. Changing target is not a option for me.

Comment: .NET Framework doesn't support `GetECDiffieHellmanPrivateKey` either, **only** .NET 6+ supports `GetECDiffieHellmanPrivateKey`. How did/do you plan to support EC crypto on .NET Framework then?

Comment: Using Bouncy Castle nuget package

Comment: [`BouncyCastle` supports .NET Standard 2.0 too](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/BouncyCastle.Crypto.csproj), so why not just use that for all targets instead?

Comment: Yup, it supports ;) - the only missing key in that puzzle is private key from cert store. In worst case I'll fallback to reading private key from .key file but first I want to check if is it possible to keep using Cert Store.

Comment: You could change your library project to use multi-targeting and use `#if NET6_OR_GREATER` for `GetECDiffieHellmanPrivateKey` and `#elif NETSTANDARD2_0_OR_GREATER` for BouncyCastle.